# Cleaning up phone related tags

Tags: discussion, status-completed, burninate-request, retag-request

I'm surprised that I couldn't find a post about it yet, since those tags are in seemingly bad state (at least after some quick look through the tags).

I wanna note that I didn't look through all of the tags or in much detail since I ain't really interested in phone related technologies and don't have much knowledge about it, also it are multiple tags, but I hope to bring attention to those tags, some of you guys should know better than me how to handle them.

The worst by far seems to be [phone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/phone), but others could need cleanup too, like [mobile-phones](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mobile-phones), [cellphone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cellphone), [telephone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/telephone), <s>[call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/call)</s>

## Let's start with [phone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/phone)

**Tagwiki:**

> A telephone, or phone, is a telecommunications device that permits two or more users to conduct a conversation when they are not in the same vicinity of each other to be heard directly.

First of it currently got 1827 questions,

- [of which 701 are tagged](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/phone%20windows) both [windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/windows) and [phone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/phone), most of which (if not all should be replaced with [windows-phone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/windows-phone) (this is how I found these tags and the thing that irks me the most).
- [488 questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/phone%20android) tagged with both [android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android) and [phone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/phone), possibly to distinguish between android phones and android tablets, other devices. I don't know if that's a good usage for it and if it shouldn't rather have new [android-phone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-phone), [android-tablet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-tablet) tags, after all that would be close to the [iphone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/iphone) and [ipad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ipad) tags that exist.
- [105 questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/phone%20call) tagged with [phone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/phone) and [call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/call) which strikes me as some misuse of the tag and they should probably added to the 165 questions already in [phone-call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/phone-call)
- [87 questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/phone%20numbers) tagged with [phone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/phone) and [numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/numbers) that should probably be tagged [phone-number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/phone-number). Many of these questions are about phone number validation, format or how to get a phone number from the contacts.
- [62 that are tagged](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/phone%20ios) [ios](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ios) and [phone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/phone), even though [iphone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/iphone) should probably be used instead.

## About [mobile-phones](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mobile-phones) and [cellphone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cellphone)

I don't know what's the difference between the two but after a quick look at the questions they seem to attract the same kind of questions. There are 363 [mobile-phones](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mobile-phones) and 98 [cellphone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cellphone) questions at the moment. Just as a note, a significant number of both tags come in combination with the [android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android) tag, which again might speak for a specific [android-phone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-phone) that I mentioned earlier already.

But the main difference is really that I don't see a difference between them with only [mobile-phones](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mobile-phones) having a tag wiki.

## <s>The ambiguous [call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/call) multi-tag?</s>

<s>**Tagwiki:**</s>

> In programming, a call is the site of invocation of a subroutine of code which when completed will return execution to the next instruction following the invocation of the call. A call is distinct from a jump in that there is no expectation of return after a jump.
>
> In telephony, a call is when one device makes a connection to another device to establish a connection.

So I get it, the tag seems to address two completely different things which I don't think is good, but I'll leave that out for now in this post (feel free to address it in the comments/answers too). Fact is that many of the questions tagged [phone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/phone), [mobile-phones](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mobile-phones), [cellphone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cellphone) also include this [call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/call) tag, and should probably be changed to the [phonecalls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/phonecalls) tag which would more than double the 166 questions it currently got, there's also to note that whilst [android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android) isn't really a problematic tag for me in the way I talked about the other tags here, but there also seem to be a lot of questions tagged with [call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/call) which might be candidates to tag as [phonecalls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/phonecalls).

## A last section on [telephone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/telephone)

This tag really isn't much of a tag to be honest, only 82 questions, many if not all about how to format telephone numbers or validating them (should probably be retagged [phone-number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/phone-number)), or about telephone calls (should probably be retagged [phonecalls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/phonecalls)).

## Other things I have to say

I really don't know much about mobile programming and related technologies but even to me these tags seem a bit thrown together and there are a lot of questions that should obviously be retagged, some others that might not be clear cut, but those tags really need a makeover. As for cleanup, burniation of some of them, I got both my magical soap and pet dragon ready, just tell me what you guys think on these tags.

Comment: I don't know about Android and the rest, but [ios] + [phone] does not necessarily equal [iphone]. There's phone stuff you can do with an iPad, which also runs iOS.

Comment: I have improved the [call] wiki so that it is more clear and refers users to [phonecalls] for the telephone concept.  Also, there is another tag [telephony] that might also be closely related.

Comment: @JoshCaswell But then that's [tag:ios] and [tag:tablet].

Comment: For the majority of iOS questions, @QPaysTaxes, the hardware is irrelevant.

Comment: @JoshCaswell ...I never said it was. As far as I can tell from a quick glance at the actual tags, [ios + tablet](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ios%20tablet?mode=all) is all about iPads, and [ios + phone](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ios%20phone?mode=any) is all about iPhones.

Comment: [tag:cellphone] is gone now

Comment: I'm going to go ahead and agree with Vadim here. The [[tag:call]] tag *definitely* needs to be a separate request, because many of the questions with that tag don't even have anything to do with phones. The [[tag:mobile-phones]] tag does still need to be cleaned up, and could arguably be handled under this request, but it's a bit too unclear and unwieldy, given that all the other tags discussed here have been successfully burninated. So, if you want to clean up either of those, go ahead and post a separate [[meta-tag:retag-request]]. I'm marking this one as [[meta-tag:status-completed]].

Comment: @CodyGray thanks! my main idea was that when there are several tags in a single request, it is often stuck in 'in-progress' state for a long time, with some parts of it completed, some in-progress, and some declined. It is better to create separate requests and finish them one by one.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is finished! I've gone through [phone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/phone) and [cellphone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cellphone) questions and cleaned them up, improving and retagging with another tags. Those tags are now gone.

[telephone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/telephone) was cleared previously. There is still a lot of work to be done on cleaning up [call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/call) and [mobile-phones](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mobile-phones) questions, but I think there should be a separate request on Meta for that.

Here are some tips:

- [windows-phone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/windows-phone) was used for [windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/windows)+[phone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/phone) questions.
- <s>[phonecalls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/phonecalls)</s> was used for questions regarding phone calls (now there is [phone-call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/phone-call))
- [phone-number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/phone-number) was used for questions regarding phone number formatting, validation, etc.
- [responsive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/responsive) + [html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/html) were used for questions about responsive websites on mobile.
- [cellular-network](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cellular-network) for questions regarding this type of thing.
- [mobile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mobile) was used for questions that are related to mobile devices (other cases)

Comment: Related request for [tag:call] - https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255920/burninate-retag-call