# Burninate/Retag [call]

Tags: discussion, tags, burninate-request

[call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/call) (3856 questions now) is confusing. The description says:

> "Call" may refer to originating a conversation by telephone, or may refer to executing a subroutine in code.

Searching for call results in finding questions which are unrelated to the expected result.

Also, 78% ([query here](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/197149/tag-occurence-in-title?TagName=call)) of the questions contain "call" already in the title.

Options:

- Retag one "piece" to [phone-call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/phone-call)
- Retag one "piece" to [method-call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/method-call)
- Retag both
- Burninate call
- Leave it as it is (please don't)

Comment: [tag:calling] is in the exact same boat. And we already have [tag:phonecalls] by the way.

Comment: +1 for retagging where appropriate and getting rid of [tag:call].

Comment: "Phone calls are a modern way of communication." Wut? That's it? Are tag-wiki editors underpaid? Oh, well, I fixed it.

Comment: @bjb568 I rejected one of the edits due a grammar error. Please take care of it

Comment: @MarcoA. Hey, I'm underpaid too.

Comment: retag both.  Only doing one would result in the one theoretically keeping the old tag still being abused as a dumpster for both types of questions.

Comment: Related https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/283187/synonymise-function-call-function-calls-method-call-call

Answer (score 1):

Ambiguous tags names will inevitably cause misuse of the tags. So all usages of [call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/call) should be retagged or burninated.

As the alternatives already exist, the disambiguation process can be achieved by:

- Retagging to [phone-call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/phone-call) where appropriate
- Retagging to [method-call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/method-call) where appropriate
- ([unsure how to retag video-calls](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bcall%5D+video+is%3Aq))

Eventually:

- Use [voip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/voip) where appropriate
- Use [incoming-call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/incoming-call) or [outgoing-call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/outgoing-call) or [dialing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dialing) where appropriate