# Why keep a tag which says -" This tag is not recommended. It could be considered ambiguous, and has no real search value."

Tags: discussion, status-completed, burninate-request

I recently found a question tagged with [calling](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/calling/info) tag. I had never encountered it earlier, so, I clicked on it. This is what it said - *This tag is not recommended. It could be considered ambiguous, and has no real search value.* . Why keep it?. Any reason why it is not *burninated*?

Comment: Maybe so users do not keep recreating it? Sometimes it's more useful to leave something with a large "do not use" sign instead of burying it completely.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi I thought that's what tag blacklisting was for?

Comment: @JonK, blacklisting is an extreme measure (only SE devs can do that). Maybe that tag was not deemed enough of a nuisance to put out the big guns.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi - I think a *Tag name* should make sense as soon as we see it. *Calling* isn't making any sense.

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255920/burninate-retag-call

Comment: With [tag:call] having 2400+ questions and [tag:calling] having a further 200, it's possible that nobody has felt up to the task of carrying out the retagging/burninating yet.

Comment: @JonK - Each question under the *calling* tag is unrelated.

Comment: @TheLostMind: funny enough, [the fifth post in the list](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25029035/how-to-get-the-dialled-number-in-parallel-calling-in-asterisk) is actually *about* calling. (It seems to be the only one.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's no reason to keep tags like that. As [JonK mentioned in the comments](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/268367/why-keep-a-tag-which-says-this-tag-is-not-recommended-it-could-be-considered#comment76065_268367), it's probably stuck around because nobody has taken the time to go through all 200+ questions and review them. Useless tags with very few instances get cleaned up quickly. Ambiguous tags with a lot of uses will sometimes warrant an organized community clean-up. 200 is somewhere in the middle. It's not a huge problem that needs to be dealt with immediately, and it's not a small problem that's easy for one person to deal with. Now that there's a question here tagged [burninate-request](/questions/tagged/burninate-request), it might get enough attention to be cleaned up.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to provide a clear definition for a tag. Then people may use it properly. If it is really just a redirect ("calling" should have been tagged "call") then put that in the tag definition. If 200 people did it, then probably 200 more will, so it is better to define than attempt to kill weeds.

See my answer about [the non-functional](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/280860/does-the-tag-non-functional-provide-any-value) tag.

Comment: People don't read the tag wikis. At least, not the people that are using terrible tags or incorrect tags. See, for instance, [this meta question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271356/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-do-not-use-tags) about tags with "DO NOT USE" in the tag wiki that are _still_ being used.  Most tags brought up in these burnination requests are bad tags (or misidentified as bad and the OP is steered right with an answer) that are ambiguous and really don't help to categorize the question.