# Do we need [phone] [call] and [mobile-phones]?

Tags: discussion, tags, burninate-request

Do we need [phone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/phone)[call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/call) and [mobile-phones](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mobile-phones)?

We already have [mobile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mobile) and [cellphone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cellphone).

### Can we burinate them?

[image]

Or should we merge as follows (based on the feedback):

- [call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/call) into [phonecalls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/phonecalls)
- [phone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/phone),[mobile-phones](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mobile-phones),[cellphone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cellphone) into [mobile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mobile)

Thoughts?

Comment: I think [mobile] is the only one of these tags we need.

Comment: Should we make [mobile-phones] a synonym for [mobile] ([mobile] is master)?

Comment: I wouldn't complain if calls was killed, but I can see calls as a separate tag for questions about actually making and receiving phone calls.  That's a separate idea than a mobile computer.

Comment: @GabeSechan: It might be useful to have a phone-call tag for them (yes, please), but a generic call-tag is much too prone to being used as fluff on this site.

Comment: @Deduplicator I'm ok with calling it phonecall instead of call, which is admittedly a more generic term (could mean a function call or something like that).

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/268367/2564301 Especially note JonK's comment on the vast number of mis-tags using [call].

Comment: The call tag is mostly used for function calls,subroutine calls, not phone calls.

Comment: Yes, [call] should possibly be burninated, but definitely not blindly merged into [phonecalls].

Comment: [call] could be for the function `call()` in VBA. I don't think it is related to "phonecalls".

Comment: @BilltheLizard Phone calls and mobile devices don't **have** to have anything to do with each other, and often don't.  Let's not go overboard with removing useful context (or the ability to add useful context).

Comment: [tag:mobile] and [tag:phone] are gone now.