# What's the [n] tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

The [n](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/n) tag has a total of 6 questions about creating SQL tables in VB.net, moving files in Python, the `%n` prinf format specifier in C, getting a subset in R, and choice of version management tool in node.js. There is no wiki.

What is this tag supposed to be about? Should we remove it?

Comment: [tag:n] is completely pointless - it should be removed from those questions and deleted.

Comment: Let's burninate it?

Comment: Problem solved!

Comment: Similarly I found some more like [tag:mo],[tag:cache-money] even the all tags related with [tag:money]

Comment: It could be useful for the programming language N. Either the long-dead macro assembler on top of NASM, or the language with Lisp syntax that compiles to MacRuby, or some other even more popular and important N.

Comment: It has reappeared with 33 questions and the description _“n is a CLI for managing multiple Node.js versions”_. Can we rename this tag to [tag:node.js-n] or so?

Answer (score 2):

The tag is now depopulated, and will be automatically removed the next time the cleanup script runs.

If it was a higher traffic tag, we might want to add a note to the tag wiki warning users not to use it.

Comment: The effectiveness of adding a warning to the tag wiki is dubious *at best*...

Comment: @Makoto: It worked for [tag:tutorials]...

Comment: [...but not for a whole host of others.](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271356/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-do-not-use-tags)

Comment: And I just realized said tag is actually blacklisted anyway.

Comment: It's so ineffective that I've got [a SEDE search to find them all](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/266086/tags-which-should-not-be-used). We're nearing 100 results (as of right now), if that gives you any indicator.

Comment: @Kevin: At least a few of those tags are obvious false positives, just on the first results page.