# Burninate the [history] tag

Tags: discussion, tags, burninate-request

We have a [history](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/history) tag.

It's wiki begins with "DO NOT USE THIS TAG". It has more than 1400 questions using it.

Why do we have this tag, if it is not to be used?

Comment: I still think these tags that will (hopefully) *eventually* be cleaned up should be locked (blacklisted) ASAP [to prevent making future cleanup efforts](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/385685/tags-can-be-locked-to-prevent-their-usage-should-we-lock-the-do-not-use-tags-wh) more difficult. Bad tags can't just be *removed*, but the developers have the ability to at least prevent them from being added to *new* questions

Comment: Strongly related: [What is the purpose of the “DO NOT USE” tags?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/271356/7296893). Also, we nearly never blacklist tags, only if they're persistently re-created after removal. The history tag hasn't been removed yet, so surely is not a blacklist candidate.

Answer (score 3):

It's still here because the burnination process where old questions on bad tags are reviewed and either cleaned up or closed (and frequently deleted) is massively backed up.  It was IIRC a >5 year backlog this summer; and had ground to a complete halt as a result of the fiasco around de-modding Monica.  The tag that was being burned at that time has finally been finished; but no new burn activity appears to've taken place since then.

[How do tag removal (burnination) requests work?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/250933/how-do-tag-removal-burnination-requests-work)