# Why is there an invisible comment on this post?

Tags: support, bug, comments

I wanted to see a comment on this post: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/392387/1839439

When I click on the button to show 1 comment nothing shows up. What's going on here? Is there some invisible comment or is this a bug?

> [image]

Comment: Blame caching. Refresh the page.

Comment: I did refresh. I did ctrl+f5.

Comment: No-repro on this end. Tried Chrome and Safari and the mobile app (all on iOS). I see no comments and no comment prompts.

Comment: reproduced on chrome on android

Comment: [Seems like another race condition](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/322853/show-x-more-comments-not-doing-anything)

Comment: reproduced also on firefox

Comment: From my experience on Firefox, You'll see a comment notification when the comment is added, but it is not removed if the comment is deleted before you view it.  This can also happen when a post is closed as a duplicate.

Comment: The comment in question added nothing of value, either directly or as dubious entertainment.   You didn't miss anything.