# Splitting [maxwell]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, retag-request, tag-disambiguation

**Problem:**

The [maxwell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/maxwell) tag seems to be used for two unrelated topic:

1. A microarchitecture for GPUs by [Nvidia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nvidia)
2. A technology to read MySQL databases in real time and write changes towards a [Kafka](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/apache-kafka) topic (or other platform)

The [tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/maxwell/info) refers to the microarchitecture. Meaning the [kafka](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/kafka)-related posts are tagged wrong.

**Suggestion:**

My suggestion would be to divide the tag into something like [maxwell-kafka](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/maxwell-kafka) and [maxwell-nvidia](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/maxwell-nvidia) and retag the posts accordingly.

---

**Priority**: low

**Posts in tag**: 7 (as of 2022-08-01)

---

**Status-Update:**

- All Nvidia related post have been removed thanks to [@Braiam](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/792066/braiam) [@Peter Cordes](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/224132/peter-cordes)
- I made a suggest edit for the maxwell-tag:

  - Excerpt: https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/32397642 (Approved)
  - Info: https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/32397641 (Approved)

Comment: Nvidia uses do not need a tag. They either use cuda (which is a unified api that supposedly doesn't care what card you are running on) which writing code is on topic, or use the other api's that nvidia cards support (be it graphic or computational apis). But most questions I've seen about nvidia cards are literally about the hardware itself, nothing programming about it (despite including the cuda tag!).

Comment: So just rename the tag, edit the wiki and remove the Nvidia related post from the tag?

Comment: No, remove the questions that are off topic first, then we figure out what's left (the mysql to kafka thing doesn't look programming to me either).

Comment: You are welcome to do so, my suggest edit queue is already full (not 2k rep yet).

Answer (score 7):

**We don't need tags for GPU microarchitectures**, just like we don't generally need them for CPU microarchitectures, just actual *architecture* like [nvidia](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/nvidia)[ptx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ptx).  (A debated exception being ARM Cortex-m and even [cortex-m3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cortex-m3) and [cortex-m0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cortex-m0), although I think last time that came up the consensus was that those are more specific than they should be, and shouldn't have been created.)

Arguably the situation is a little different than different CPU microarchitectures implementing the same ISA, because NVidia does change the machine code between microarchitectures, with a PTX virtual ISA with an optimizing compiler to target the actual hardware.  But until we get any significant number of questions about writing code for the instruction-set the GPU hardware can execute directly, we don't need tags like [nvidia-pascal], just like we don't need [haswell] or [intel-haswell], or [amd-zen] (which don't exist and I have no plan to create them.)  Tagging [x86][cpu-architecture] has proved sufficient to collect together the questions about CPU performance details and/or instruction-set extensions that differ between microarchitectures for the same ISA.

---

I retagged [CUDA caches data into the unified cache from the global memory to store them into the shared memory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36735233/cuda-caches-data-into-the-unified-cache-from-the-global-memory-to-store-them-int) and [What are the access times for different GPU memory spaces?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30371708/what-are-the-access-times-for-different-gpu-memory-spaces) to [nvidia](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/nvidia) instead of [maxwell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/maxwell).  Those were the only GPU uses of the tag when I searched.

The string "maxwell" appears inside the posts, and is a unique enough word that searching on [nvidia](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/nvidia) + [maxwell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/maxwell) won't have a lot of false-positives about other uses of "maxwell".  For that and other reasons, it's 100% fine to not have a tag for this at all.

We have one for [kepler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/kepler) with a tag description that specifies it as NVIDIA, but unless/until that becomes an actual problem (ambiguity with some software name), we don't need to remove it.  Since it's not a very current microarchitecture, it's unlikely to get tagged on many new questions.  (Although having it exist sets a precedent that might encourage others to create new tags for other uarches.)  As far as I'm concerned, it's not worth the effort and noise to remove [kepler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/kepler).

Due to the 5-tag limit, I also replaced [kepler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/kepler) with [gpgpu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gpgpu) on the question about cache/memory access times, since that question wasn't [cuda](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cuda) specific.  Although it's not even specific to GPGPU; cache performance is I think relevant for shader programs for normal graphics use cases.  (The [gpu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gpu) tag was already present.)

I considered adding [cpu-architecture](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cpu-architecture) since that's the catch-all tag for microarchitecture details, but nominally only for CPUs.  Probably best to keep it only for actual CPUs.

---

#### Update: [kepler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/kepler) also has non-GPU uses, more than GPU recently

- "Eclipse Kepler" is some version of the IDE
- There's some JavaScript thing called Kepler, perhaps related to react.js
- At least one question about orbital mechanics using Kepler's equations, the actual scientist the other projects are named after :P
- The newest GPU/CUDA question tagged [kepler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/kepler) is from 2018

[How to apply filter , time visualization in kepler.gl Through code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61542319/how-to-apply-filter-time-visualization-in-kepler-gl-through-code) has [kepler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/kepler) as its only tag; the code mentions React.

**We should disambiguate [kepler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/kepler), perhaps removing the original.**

Comment: Maybe a low-noise but good thing to do would be to edit the tag descriptions in [tag:kepler] and [tag:maxwell]? Luckily noone tried to make [tag:pascal] about a GPU architecture.

Comment: Given that there is now no connection to the GPU microarchitectures in the questions tagged with maxwell I'd agree with @Cimbali editing the tag description. I'd go ahead with editing the maxwell-wiki to match its current use if there is no opposition.

Comment: @A-Tech: Sure, if you have a good idea for what to put in it.  Post a link to the suggested-edit here in comments so interested folks can vote to approve the review (or approve+edit which would let a single user with 20k rep approve it.)  I don't know anything about the MySQL Maxwell, or much about databases myself.

Comment: @Cimbali: yeah good point, I'll edit [kepler] to add a "DO NOT USE" note or something tomorrow when I have time, assuming nobody objects in the meantime.

Comment: "We don't need tags for GPU microarchitectures" "We have one for [kepler] [...] but unless/until that becomes an actual problem [...] we don't need to remove it" That message in itself is ambiguous. We either do not need tags for gpu arch or we need 'em. Have to be consistent man.

Comment: @Braiam: If we already have something we don't need, it's not always worth the work and edit noise to get rid of it.  Adding a DO NOT USE notice should be sufficient to reduce new tagging of it.

Comment: @PeterCordes are you new here? [I think you need to read more closely the second paragraph of this answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/271443/792066), if you believe what your comment says. Also, it's always worthy to get rid of trash of the system, _always_.

Comment: @Braiam: I'm well aware that DO NOT USE doesn't do much, but it doesn't *hurt*.  I suggested it would be good enough in *this* case because new questions tagged [kepler] are unlikely as it's fairly old at this point, not as relevent.  Not at all like the examples in the question you linked, such as [history] or [fuzzy].  If you want to clean up all the [tag:kepler] questions, feel free, but don't go removing other tags that are still relevant just because you dislike most tags.

Comment: @Braiam: Actually, after looking at the question list, it seems there are non-GPU uses of [kepler], so it's a problem too, and needs more disambiguation work than [maxwell] did.

Comment: @PeterCordes To suggest edit has been added to the question

Comment: @A-Tech: Ok, I voted to approve it. There's no edit pending for the main tag wiki yet (https://stackoverflow.com/tags/maxwell/info), just the excerpt.  They both need to change.

Comment: @PeterCordes thanks, added the suggest for main info aswell.

Comment: @PeterCordes "doesn't do much" is an understatement: it does absolutely nothing. "but it doesn't hurt" it hurts because people that actually try to do something are being prevented from addressing the problem with an action that does nothing. Nice words would never address the problem.

Comment: @Braiam: How does a "DO NOT USE" note in a tag excerpt prevent anyone from doing things like untagging [kepler]?  If anything, it's helpful for that, because it reduces the amount of possible confusion when people see edits that remove the tag; they can check the mouseover.  Or do you mean it prevents them from editing the tag to instead be about some other meanings of the same word?

Comment: @A-Tech: ok, approved via an "approve + edit" to add a mention of the previous usage, and what to tag for the GPU use-case.

Comment: It is a bit surreal to read you say this, as you clearly support having an [x86] tag. What is the difference? Why would we not have tags for CPU and GPU ISAs? This makes no sense to me. Cortex-M3 and Cortex-M0 might be too granular; I could understand a proposal to merge them both into Cortex-M (although I see counter-arguments, too). But leading off with the argument that we shouldn't have microarchitecture tags is a big WTF...

Comment: @CodyGray: We don't have and don't want separate tags for [haswell] vs. [nehalem] vs. [amd-zen], just [intel] or [amd-processor] + [x86].  And AFAIK it's very rare to program GPUs at any lower level than the portable PTX assembly language which works across all microarchitectures.

Comment: @CodyGray: I guess the situation isn't exactly analogous because there *is* a software-visible assembly language that's specific to each generation of GPU, so in CPU terms they'd be different *architectures*?  I don't know how much this differs between kepler/maxwell/pascal, but if we start getting enough Q&As that lumping them together into [nvidia][gpu] is a problem, we can make tags like [nvidia-pascal], which will be active for a few years until that generation of GPUs is obsolete. (That obsolescence is a factor in thinking it shouldn't have tags; but OTOH [c++11] has a tag.)