# Does the tag [non-functional] provide any value?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, burninate-request

I came across a question with the tag [non-functional](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/non-functional).  There is no tag wiki for this, and there are now 17 questions tagged with it (I removed the tag from the eighteenth question).  The majority of the questions are to do with 'non-functional requirements', though a few of them seem to be more related to 'non-functional code' (probably meaning "my code is broken").

I'm thinking that the tag should be removed from these questions and hence from the site altogether.  If someone wanted to create and document a 'non-functional-requirements' tag, that would be OK with me for the questions about non-functional requirements, but it doesn't seem to be an urgently needed tag.

Any reason not to burninate [non-functional](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/non-functional)?

---

*Thanks to whoever else has gone through the questions removing the tags where possible.*

Having gone through most of the questions (the number is down to 11 now), there are a number where the dual tags 'non-functional' and 'requirements' are the only tags on the question. Deleting the non-functional tag may not be a help. I'm sympathetic to "should be closed" — and any of the reasons 'off-topic', 'too broad' or 'unclear what you're asking' could usually be applied. I'm not clear whether another site is suitable: [Programmers](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/) might be OK as [Ben Voigt](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/103167/ben-voigt) [suggests](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/280860/does-the-tag-non-functional-provide-any-value#comment132764_280860), though they might not welcome the influx of not-very-insightful questions (and most of the questions are too old to be migrated anyway, so they are spared the problem because of the embargo on migrating old questions).

Comment: That's a ridiculously broad tag. "non-functional" can apply to basically every other question I see in Android. I definitely think it should be removed.

Comment: I imagine that it could have some meaning were it used to refer to code that has side-effects (i.e. not purely functional), but I don't see it being used like that, so probably not worth keeping.

Comment: Is [non-functional-requirements] actually a short enoug tag to be valid? If yes, we can retag some of them and let the roomba take care of [non-functional]

Comment: Requirements questions don't belong on StackOverflow to begin with.  Maybe Programmers.SE

Comment: Sure the word provides value.  That tag is non-functional.  Don't bother asking us when you can clean it up in a few minutes.

Comment: @BenVoigt: Ways to check them programmatically might work here though.

Comment: @Deduplicator: I think that's impossible for non-functional requirements, by definition?

Comment: @BenVoigt: Isn't testing for performance-regressions for example a non-functional test, though it can be done programmatically? Or am I seeing functional requirements too narrow here?

Comment: @Deduplicator In a hard or soft real-time environment, performance is functional. Industrial control is hard real-time. Games are soft real-time because all but a fraction of a percent of frames need to be up in 16 ms. Web is soft real-time because users click away after 7 seconds.

Comment: **Non-functional requirements** are common in enterprise SDLC, pertaining to requirements that are not immediately (or sometimes never) perceived by the user: reliability, durability, resilience, security, maintainability, adherence to coding style norms, test coverage etc., etc., aka stuff that doesn't drive short term ROI and that CIO's can't easily sell to the business.   (And, that the FBI couldn't sell to the DNC.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For better or worse, there are no questions left with the (now non-functional) [non-functional](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/non-functional) tag.

Someone else can chase down and clean up the questions with the [requirements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/requirements) tag.

Comment: For Worse. It has a very valid and useful definition, pertinent to Requirements Definition, and Computing generally, which is spelled out in the literature. (See my answer.) Vote it back in!

Comment: @nocomprende: Why do you think [tag:non-functional] is desirable without a qualifying term like [tag:non-functional-requirements]?  It most likely isn't desirable.  There's nothing I can do to stop you adding the tag (either tag), but you'll need enough privilege to do so.  The unqualified tag, though, is really not helpful for searching.  If I spotted it in use, I'd most probably remove it; it would depend on the tag wiki entry, etc.  (No tag wiki, no tag — that is, without a justification for the tag, it would be appropriate to remove it again.)

Comment: So, as I said in my (downvoted) answer below: 'If the tag "non-functional" was simply given a very narrow and pertinent definition...' Which is what someone should have done. THEN determine if the questions fit, and remove the useless questions. Cleaning up something does not have to mean removing it. Pruning a plant often makes it better. This is an example of a distinct lack of vision in these sites overall - too literal!

Answer (score -3):

Are tags that were removed as being non-useful then prevented from being re-created? This is like how if you opt out of future emails, there must be a database saying "and DON'T add me back in again!". I think we might end up with a longer set of non-useful (invisible, not allowed) tags than useful ones, but something has to regulate the quality of the site.

Personally, I think that for completeness you have to include things that are non-functional. Like Null in databases... It could not be legislated away. If the tag "non-functional" was simply given a very narrow and pertinent definition, then we would not have this come up again. Pro-active rather than reactive.

Comment: Not completely.  Newcomers to the site can't recreate the tag.  It won't be offered in lists of tags.  Those features dramatically reduce the chances of it reappearing.  (I note that what you've written is not really an answer — it is more of an adjunct question, one that would be better expressed as a comment if you had the reputation to permit commenting.)

Comment: "Buddha provide" rep to *Comment Everywhere* now.

Answer (score -5):

Here is another definition of **non-functional** to do with requirements (stated or not) from this paper - *[Revisiting Information Hiding: Reflections on Classical and Nonclassical Modularity](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~ckaestne/pdf/ecoop11.pdf)*:

> If a stakeholder wants to reason about "nonfunctional" aspects of a
>   system, **such as time or space complexity or power consumption**, he
>   probably needs to reason about implementation details hidden behind
>   abstraction barriers.

So, this tag is very useful, it just needs a definition. "*If [it] did not exist, it would be necessary to invent [it].*" - Voltaire

Comment: I guess from the **Downvotes** that this Answer went over everyones' head. Why should *programmers* worry about things like whether something is efficient, will fit in memory, not run too long, etc? We're beyond all that nowadays. What? My phone? Battery chronically runs down? **Non-Functional!!!**