# Does this tag have any [functionality]?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, burninate-request

*This tag has been burninated. Please do not recreate it. If you need advice on which tag to use, see the answer below. If you see this tag reappearing, it may need to be blacklisted.*

---

Should the [functionality](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/functionality) tag be burninated?

Looking at [the rules](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/239190/when-to-burninate/239191#239191):

- It seems like a classical case of a meta-tag. I can hardly imagine any question to which this tag would not apply.
- There are currently 138 questions with the [functionality](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/functionality) tag, and they don't seem to have anything in common. The related tags include half a dozen programming languages, and beyond that, everything from [ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ajax) over [class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/class) to [documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/documentation) ...
- I cannot imagine a question for which it adds any value. It mainly seems to be thrown in randomly in arbitrary questions, maybe as a filler, or (and this is the larger problem) instead of a *better tag*.

Related: [Does the tag 'non-functional' provide any value?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/280860/does-the-tag-non-functional-provide-any-value)

Comment: Stats at the start of featuring: Q: 80/-4, A1 (saying Yes) 3/0.

Comment: Someone should male the title a pun.

Comment: True @Sweeper, but we [avoid using puns during the formal burnination](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/324070/what-is-the-process-for-tag-removal-burnination) procedure. Once it's completed [we can add back the pun](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260218/all-the-movement-has-ceased).

Comment: `Yes, we should`

Comment: Let it burninate.

Comment: Stats at the end of featuring: Q: 150/-5, A1 (saying Yes) 67/0. The community has voted in favor of the burnination.

Answer (score 67):

I agree with this burnination. As the post mentions, [functionality](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/functionality) is not a tag which is worthy of being kept. I looked at the post, and many of the questions were either off topic or wrongly tagged. Some examples of wrongly tagged posts are:

- Questions related to functions, where we need to use the [function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/function) tag instead.
- Questions related to built-in functions of a programming language: Here the [built-in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/built-in) (along with [function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/function), if necessary) can be used instead.
- Questions related to the functional programming paradigm, which needs to be tagged [functional-programming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/functional-programming) instead.

The off-topic posts were related to either browser functionalities or app functionalities, which would be on topic on either Super User or Web Applications. The ones which I checked were very old, and hence we can't migrate them.

Most of the remaining questions were related to the word "functionality" (like, functionality of button, functionality of an app, etc) and not about any programming concept. In these cases, the tag shouldn't have been present (similar to a meta-tag).  This includes the [15 questions tagged along with Jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/functionality+jquery) and the [13 tagged along with Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/functionality+javascript). They are all mostly related to whether a particular functionality is present in the concept or not. (I chose those two, as they [are the top related tags in the post](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/functionality/topusers)).

To bolster our demand to burninate,

1. It [doesn't have a tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/functionality/info), which would have helped us guide the users to tag properly.
2. There are [no top users in the tag](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/functionality/topusers), who could have explained us the use of the tag and helped create a wiki.

Now, answering  [the 4 questions for burnination](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/239190/when-to-burninate/239191#239191):

1. Does it describe the contents of the questions to which it is applied? and is it unambiguous?

   No. It does not describe the contents of the question at all. It does not imply as to what functionality the poster is asking about, and it certainly wouldn't be clear if that was the single tag on a question. Similarly, as mentioned above, it is totally ambiguous as to what exactly the user wants to convey when they use the tag.
2. Is the concept described even on-topic for the site?

   Partial No. I'm saying partial because built-in functionalities related to programming, etc *are* on topic to Stack Overflow. However, as we can see, many of the questions (where the tag isn't used as a meta tag) are related to browser functionalities, app functionalities, etc, which are not on topic for Stack Overflow.
3. Does the tag add any meaningful information to the post?

   No. The tag certainly is superfluous on most of the questions used. As it is being used as a meta tag in most of the posts, it is not adding any additional information to the post than what is already present. Also, as explained before most of the related tags, the tag is being used for its English definition, rather than as a programming concept. Therefore it is beyond doubt that the tag does not add any meaningful information to the post.
4. Does it mean the same thing in all common contexts?

   No. It is a bit of a stretch to agree that the tag functionality means some functionality, but it does not convey the information as to which functionality. Is it related to built-in functionality, or enhanced functionality, etc. Therefore it is clear that it does not mean the same thing in all *common* contexts.

Given all these reasons and the No answer to all the 4 questions, I think it's clear enough for the tag to be burninated.

Answer (score 3):

[functionality](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/functionality) has been *burninated*.

[image: trogdor]

Thanks to everyone who participated.

## Observations/Retag Guidance:

taken from the other answer:

- Questions related to functions, where we need to use the [function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/function) tag instead.
- Questions related to built-in functions of a programming language: Here the [built-in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/built-in) (along with [function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/function), if necessary) can be used instead.
- Questions related to the functional programming paradigm, which needs to be tagged [functional-programming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/functional-programming) instead.

## Progress:

The [functionality](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/functionality) tag is in the process of being burninated. You can help out by reviewing the questions with this tag, and...

- **editing** questions (to improve the question *and* remove the tag),
- **flagging/closing** questions that are duplicates/off-topic/unclear/too broad/opinion-based,
- filtering on this tag in the [Close Vote Queue](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/?filter-tags=functionality),
- **voting** on questions with this tag,
- voting to **delete** the questions with this tag (after they have been closed, and only if the entire Q&A contains nothing of value). However, keep in mind that at the end of the burnination process all closed questions containing this tag will be deleted automatically. Thus, there's rarely a need to vote to delete these questions.

Here are some quick links to get you started:

- [Open](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bfunctionality%5D+closed%3Ano)
- [Closed](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bfunctionality%5D+closed%3Ayes)
- [Unanswered](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bfunctionality%5D+answers%3A0+closed%3Ano)
- [No Accepted Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bfunctionality%5D+hasaccepted%3A0+closed%3Ano)

## [Track progress of the burnination!](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177679/burnination-progress-for-the-functionality-tag)

[image]

## Remember that burnination is a *clean-up* effort!

#### Salvage whatever possible by editing and re-tagging.

We don't want to destroy value, so salvaging a post should be your first priority. If a question can be saved, please edit it. Your edit should improve *all* problems with the question *and* remove the [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tag) tag, possibly replacing it with another tag, as described above in "Observations/Retag Guidance".

#### Unsalvageable questions should just be flagged/closed. They don't need to be retagged.

If the question is not appropriate for this site, then don't worry about removing the [functionality](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/functionality) tag—just flag/close the question it is attached to.

At the end of the burnination process, all questions that still remain with the [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tag) tag should have been closed. These will be mass-deleted, which will remove the tag from the system automatically, with minimal disruption.

#### Ask for help if you need it.

If you have any questions about specific questions you come across, or the process in general, please feel free to leave a comment on this post. You can also drop into the [SOCVR chat room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers) for real-time advice and discussion.