# Synonymise: function-call, function-calls, method-call, call

Tags: discussion, status-completed, retag-request, clean-up

For questions related to calling functions/methods, we have four possible tags:

[function-call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/function-call), [function-calls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/function-calls), [method-call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/method-call), [call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/call)

It seems that at least the first three tags should be synonyms (since a method is just an object-oriented name for a function).

[After some discussion](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255920/burninate-retag-call) the `call` tag is now (at least in theory) supposed to contain questions about subroutine calls.  Whether or not this is sufficiently different from a function call is a matter of opinion,... on which you can vote.

Comment: I don't have enough rep on these tags to synonymise, so if anyone would like to do make the appropriate changes that would be useful, thanks.

Comment: The terms are too strongly correlated to a language.  A C++ programmer will foam at the mouth when his function is called "method".  A C# programmer will foam when his method sounds like a vb.net "Function".  Do nothing, there is no point in getting anybody upset over a contextual tag.

Comment: @HansPassant I thought that the whole point of synonyms is that you can type any of the phrases: the advantage is that you get a single info page, and (more importantly) you don't have to track several keywords to find the complete set of related questions.  So C# people can type `method-call` and VB people can type `function-call`, and everyone is happy.

Comment: Everybody is already happy, you are trying to fix a non-existing problem.  Creating a new problem in the process, a tag synonym renames the tag under the question.

Answer (score 4):

Synonymise all four tags. [function-call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/function-call), [function-calls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/function-calls), [method-call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/method-call), [call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/call) mean the same thing.

Answer (score 4):

Synonymise [function-call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/function-call) and [function-calls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/function-calls), but leave [method-call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/method-call) and [call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/call) separate.

Comment: I've synonymized it this way, as there was some debate regarding method-call and function-call in the comments on the question.

Answer (score -1):

Synonymise [function-call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/function-call), [function-calls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/function-calls), [method-call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/method-call) but leave [call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/call) separate.

Answer (score -2):

Do nothing.  [function-call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/function-call), [function-calls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/function-calls), [method-call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/method-call), [call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/call) all have important semantic differences.